# Ajax POST issue with comment system

Tags: ajax, forms

I downloaded a php/ajax comment script almost 2 years ago and been having this small issue since day one. I tried to contact the author, but he's no where to be found.

Sometimes when I click the "Send" button, the button stays disabled and nothing happens at all. It just continues to show the animated busy picture. I do not receive any error messages at all.

I'm wondering if any of you pros can help me with this?

Here is the relevant code :

```
<div class="comment_heading">Leave a Comment</div>
<div class="post_comment">
<textarea name="txtpostcomment" id="txtpostcomment-'.$postid.'" class="txtpostcomment"></textarea>
<button class="btnpostcomment" id="btnpostcomment-'.$postid.'" onclick="comment('.$postid.');" type="button">Send</button>
<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="'.$_SESSION['token'].'">
<script>document.getElementById("txtpostcomment-'.$postid.'").focus();</script>
</div>

comment = function(postid1)
{
    var txt =  $('#txtpostcomment-'+postid1);
    var btn =  $('#btnpostcomment-'+postid1);

    var comment1 = $(txt).val();
    var token = $("#token").val();

    $(btn).css('background-image', 'url(/comments/submit-busy.gif)');
    $(btn).attr('disabled', true);

    $.post("/comments/submit.php",{commenting:1, postid:postid1, comment: comment1, name: name, token: token},
    function(msg)
    {
        if(msg.status)
        {
            $('.post_comment .error_msg').remove();
            $('.comment-list-'+postid1).prepend(msg.html);
            $(txt).val('');
            $('.comChars').empty();
        }
        else
        {
            $('.post_comment .error_msg').remove();
            $('.error_msg').clone().appendTo('.post_comment');
            $('.error_msg:last').append(msg.error);
        }

        $(btn).css('background-image', 'none');
        $(btn).attr('disabled', false);
        $(txt).attr('disabled', false);

    },'json');
}
```

Comment: $.ajax is has more options and  flexible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your code is not checking for error conditions just in case the Ajax request fails (due to network disconnection, server error etc). Check your javascript console for any js errors. Since it is using `$.post` you might want to extend the code to add error handling if the jQuery version that you are using supports it. Or, alternatively, use `$.ajax`. For more info see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post or http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax